# Image file is not shown in CodeSandBox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codesandbox

I made a code using React and the code is working well if I run the code in local.

I moved the same code to 'CodeSandBox'. But the image files in the directory don't be shown.
I also made the same code using JavaScipt and it's also working well in 'CodeSandBox'.

I'll upload my code and CodeSandBox link. Would you check why it can't load image files well?

**Code**

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [valueX, setValueX] = useState(0);

  const mouseHandle = (e) => {
    setValueX(e.clientX);
  };

  return (
    <Wrap onMouseMove={mouseHandle} valueX={valueX}>
      <section>
        <div id="bg"></div>
        <h2>2.5D Parallax Effects</h2>
        <img src="img.png" className="girl" />
      </section>
    </Wrap>
  );
}

const Wrap = styled.div`
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;

  section {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  section #bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(bg.jpg);
    background-size: ${(props) => `calc(100% + ${props.valueX / 2}px)`};
    background-position: center;
  }

  section .girl {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    left: 50%;
    max-width: ${(props) => `calc(400px - ${props.valueX / 50}px)`};
  }

  section h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 8em;
    text-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transform: ${(props) =>
      `translate(calc(10% - ${props.valueX * 2}px), -50%)`};
  }
`;
```

**CodeSandBox**

React
https://codesandbox.io/s/2-5d-parallax-react-l9pdxp?file=/src/App.js

JavaScript
https://codesandbox.io/s/2-5d-parallax-javascript-ix4f5q?file=/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Codesandbox setup for React, the assets that needs to be referenced from the root path needs to be placed under the `public` directory.

Try to move your `bg.jpg` and `img.png` into the `public` directory for it to work.

---

Alternatively, the recommended solution is to move your assets (In this case `bg.jpg` and `img.png`) to be inside your `src` folder. After that, you can `import` that in your `.tsx` file and use it in your `img` tag and CSS, example below:

```
import bg from './bg.jpg';
import img from './img.png';

const element = <img src={img} alt="girl" className="girl" />;

const Wrap = styled.div`
  section #bg {
    background: url(${bg});
  }
`;
```

Comment: Thanks. Then, all the resets in CodeSandBox should be placed in public directory?

Comment: Hi @DgUZH, I have just updated my answer again, there's an alternate more preferable solution which will generate hashed image assets

Comment: Yes it could be an alternative. Thanks for your kindness @AngYC